# RxJS Subscription only works one time

Tags: angular, rxjs

In my Angular app, I'm manually validating some form data from JSON.

As such, I'm subscribing to a Subject that receives a change event:

```js
private _contentChanged = new Subject<IEditorContentChangedEvent>();
contentChanged$: Observable<IEditorContentChangedEvent>;

constructor() {
  this.contentChanged$ = this._contentChanged.asObservable();
}

onContentChanged(event: IEditorContentChangedEvent): void {
  this._contentChanged.next(event);
}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.contentChanged$
      .pipe(
        untilDestroyed(this),
        debounceTime(1000),
        filter(event => Boolean(event)),
        map(() => {
          this.resource = JSON.parse(this.fhirResourceString) as IFhirResourceType;
          console.log(this.resource);
          this.parentForm.setValue(this.resource);

          return of(event);
        }),
        catchError((error: Error) => {
          ...

          return EMPTY;
        }),
      )
      .subscribe(() => {
        ...
      });
}
```

I see the log statement in `map()` the first time contentChanged$ receives a value, but not the second time if the code in `map` throws an error.

I'm assuming this is because `catchError()` returns `EMPTY`. I've been following guides such as [this article on Medium](https://medium.com/@erVikas1/how-to-keep-an-observable-returned-by-httpclient-alive-after-error-da6c5e601e9c), but no luck so far.

I have tried returning: `of(error)` in the `catchError()` handler, but that doesn't work either.

If I just subscribe to `contentChanged$` without any operators, I see each time `_contentChanged` has received a new value, so my source of data is working as expected.

If I make a change that does not cause `catchError` to be invoked, I see the log statement in `map`, so it has to be `catchError` that's closing the stream.

How can I keep the Observable/Subscription alive to process new `contentChanged$` values?

Comment: show your `contentChanged$` property and how it interacts?

Comment: @AntonMarinenko I've added the property and the method that's called to set the next value of the Subject.

Comment: @BrandonTaylor remove operators individually to identify the one that causes the problem

Comment: I'm assuming that `untilDestroyed` is a custom operator, is it behaving as expected? You say that you see the log statement of the `finalize` operator once, but no more, well that is the desired behavior, that operator will run once the stream closes (complete or error), now, the question would be why it is closing, I would suspect of an error within the stream which triggers `catchError` and then closes the stream.

Comment: @DavidFontes `untilDestroyed` is part of the `@ngneat/until-destroy` package which is used throughout my app. `this.parentForm.setValue(this.resource)` will throw an error if the JSON provided doesn't match the expected fields. That's when `catchError` will be invoked.

Comment: @Benny Yeah, I've done that. It's the `catchError` handler.

Comment: If `setValue` causing error,it's a `javascript error`,you can wrap `setValue` with `try catch`

Comment: `EMPTY` is an observable that emits no items and terminates normally; `NEVER` is one that emits no items and doesn't terminate. Are you sure you don't want to return `NEVER` in your catchError?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I just tried that, but I get the same outcome

Comment: Instead of catching error on your original stream. You want to create another stream. Since you are concern about the error occurring on `setValue` create a stream from `this.resource` with `of()` operator and use switchMap.

Comment: @penleychan I'm about to step away from my computer, but can you point me to an example?

Comment: Here's a link for references: https://iamturns.com/continue-rxjs-streams-when-errors-occur/

Comment: @penleychan I actually found that reference earlier, but I'm not sure how to apply any of those examples to my use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your comment `setValue` is throwing error, that error is being caught in `CathError` and as per observable behaviour **source stream** will be dead after any kind of error in source stream chain(pipe) or completion of source stream

In-order to keep stream alive you need to handle this error internally -

- If any child observable causing error then

`switchMap/ConcatMap...(() => child$.pipe(catchError(...))`

- in case of plain javascript error wrap it with `try catch block`

In your case it's `JSON.parse` error,which is a javascript error,so wrapped it with `try catch`

```ts
  map(() => {
    this.resource = JSON.parse(this.fhirResourceString) as IFhirResourceType;
    console.log(this.resource);
    this.parentForm.setValue(this.resource);

    return of(event);
  }),
```

Modify above snippet with below one

```ts
  map(() => {
    try {
      this.resource = JSON.parse(this.fhirResourceString) as IFhirResourceType;
    } catch(err){
      console.error(err);
    }
    console.log(this.resource);
    this.parentForm.setValue(this.resource);

    return event;
  }),
```

Comment: This code is the answer. Could you please add some explanation as to why is it that it works? code only answers tend not to be well received by the community

Comment: This does indeed work. Is it the correct implementation because of the type of error that's being thrown? In other instances, I've used catchError when dealing with Angular HTTP requests that fail. How is this different?

Answer (score 0):

## The Observable Contract

Here's an overview: [link](https://reactivex.io/documentation/contract.html)

The relevant part:

> Upon issuing an complete or error notification, an observable may not thereafter issue any further notifications.

This means that once an observable completes or errors, it's done. They are *terminal* emissions/notifications.

---

#### One Solution:

Don't let your observable emit an error. If you know that some synchronous code in your map is throwing an error, You can catch it and deal with it there and then it'll never propagate up into your observable:

```ts
try {
  this.resource = JSON.parse(/* ... */);
} catch(err){
  console.error(err);
}
```

#### Another Solution

Once the source observable errors, just re-subscribe to your source observable. Whether this works depends on what side effects are created when you subscribe to your source in the first place.

```ts
this.contentChanged$.pipe(
  untilDestroyed(this),
  debounceTime(1000),
  filter(event => Boolean(event)),
  map(() => {
    ...
  }),
  tap({error: (error: Error) => console.error(error) }),
  // By default, if contentChanged$ keeps erroring, this will
  // keep retrying for forever.
  retry()
).subscribe(() => {
  ...
});
```

You can also conditionally retry by returning an observable from `catchError`

```ts
this.contentChanged$.pipe(
  untilDestroyed(this),
  debounceTime(1000),
  filter(event => Boolean(event)),
  map(() => {
    ...
  }),
  catchError((error: Error, source$) => {
    console.error(error)
    if (/* retry? */){
      return source$;
    } else if (/* Do nothing? */) {
      return EMPTY;
    } else if (/* Emit some string values? */) {
      return of("Hello", "World");
    } 

    // Otherwise rethrow the error!
    return throwError(() => error);
  })
).subscribe(() => {
  ...
});
```